# R - How to parallelize my mergesort

Tags: r, sorting, parallel-processing

I'm trying to make my merge became [parallel](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/) instead of sequential in R, I tried to use parallel library, but its not working (I don't know exactly how to use it, tried to put the merge function inside it, but doesn't work with my input).

My input its a txt file with one string per line and I have to sort it.

This is my sequential code:

```
#start time
strt<-Sys.time()

#merge sort
mmerge<-function(a,b) {
r<-numeric(length(a)+length(b))
ai<-1; bi<-1; j<-1;
for(j in 1:length(r)) {
  if((ai<=length(a) && a[ai]<b[bi]) || bi>length(b)) {
    r[j] <- a[ai]
    ai <- ai+1
  } else {
    r[j] <- b[bi]
    bi <- bi+1          
  }
}
r
}

mmergesort<-function(A) {
  if(length(A)>1) {
  q <- ceiling(length(A)/2)
  a <- mmergesort(A[1:q])
  b <- mmergesort(A[(q+1):length(A)])
  mmerge(a,b)
} else {
  return(A)
}
}

#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

# args test
if (length(args)==0 | length(args)==1) {
stop("Arquivo de entrada e saida devem ser fornecidos (input.txt, output.txt)", call.=FALSE)
 } 

#read file
input <- read.table(file=args[1], header=F)

#vector parser
input <- as.character(input[,1])

#sort
ordenado <- mmergesort(input)

#write file
write(ordenado, file=args[2], sep = "\t")

#end time
print(Sys.time()-strt)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use in-built functions such as `sort`? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sort.html

Comment: I mean, assuming that you have to read a file with one word per line, why just you can't use `ordered <- sort(words[,1])`. Wouldn't this be far easier?

Comment: cause must be O(nlogn) and normal sort in r is O(n).

Comment: `mergesort` already has `O(nlogn)`, you don't need to parallelize it in order to reduce the complexity. Here you have an R implementation of mergesort: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#R

Comment: I need to paralelize it to run large amounts of data (such as millions of line in the file)... And afterwards compare time difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it using after following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWgOkKorFH4) video (if u want just the code part go to 13:00-14:00):

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

[...]

#merge sort
mmerge<-function(a,b) {
  r<-numeric(length(a)+length(b))
  ai<-1; bi<-1; j<-1;
  foreach(j= 1:length(r)) %do% {
    if((ai<=length(a) && a[ai]<b[bi]) || bi>length(b)) {
      r[j] <- a[ai]
      ai <- ai+1
    } else {
  r[j] <- b[bi]
  bi <- bi+1          
  }
}
  r
}

[...]

#number of clusters
registerDoParallel(4)

#sort
ordenado <- mmergesort(input)

#stop parallel
stopImplicitCluster()

[...]
```